# NULL Custom Class Objects when outside viewDidLoad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, variables, properties, automatic-ref-counting

u1Option is an Option (custom class) object  which is
declared and called in my ViewController viewDidLoad as:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad  {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    Option *u1Option = [[Option alloc]init];

    [u1Option setName: @"test"];

    NSLog(@"Test1 Result: %@", u1Option.name);
}
```

Option is a custom class inheriting from NSObject and has a property declared in Option.h:

```
@property NSString *name;
```

However, if try to use u1Option in a IBAction, nothing is passed and while I get the "test" string in the Test1 NSLOG, on the contrary I get NULL in the Test2 NSLOG.

```
- (IBAction)addFirstOption:(UIButton *)sender {

    NSLog(@"Test2 Result: %@", u1Option.name);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Option` instance is destroyed as soon as `viewDidLoad` returns.  You need to put it in a property or instance variable. If it's already a property or instance variable then you are re-defining it, so use:

```
u1Option = [[Option alloc] init];
```

And this issue can be avoided in future by using `self.u1Option` or `_u1Option`.